# Linking correctly multiple criteria formula to another worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I will be brief as possible.  Here is a calculation that I have put together in my sheet titled "Input".

=SUMPRODUCT(--($E$11:$E$61>=$AE$5),--($E$11:$E$61<=$AF$5),--($H11:$H61=$D$330))

I've created a sheet titled "Results" that I would like to place the result of the above calculation.   Here is my latest attempt...

=SUMPRODUCT(--(Input!$E$11:$E$61>=$AE$5),--(Input!$E$11:$E$61<=$AF$5),--(Input!$H11:$H61=$D$330))

The correct answer should be 4.  However, on my Results sheet... I am coming up with 42.  Not exactly sure what I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: AE5, AF5 and D330 are all referring to the sheet on which the formula resides; so if you've moved the formula from Input to Results, you've changed the formula to refer to different cells.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld...AE5,AF5, and D330 are all set and will remain on the Input page.  The first calculation above resides in a cell to determine whether an alert first happened during a certain time, and then if that alert qualified as a YES (in the H column).

Comment: I don't understand, but here is what your formula is doing so far as the worksheets are concerned, if the formula is on the **Results** sheet:  =SUMPRODUCT(--(Input!$E$11:$E$61>= **Results** !$AE$5),--(Input!$E$11:$E$61<= **Results** !$AF$5),--(Input!$H11:$H61= **Results** !$D$330))  Is That what you want.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - if I am reading the SUMPRODUCT calculation correctly, it could be said like If E11:E61>=AE5 AND E11:E61<=AF5 (which is determining time range) AND H11:H61=$D$330 (which is YES) then the statement should come back TRUE and therefore that row gets a "1" to tablulate.  Is this correct?   All the referenced cells such as AE5,AF5, E11:E61, H11:H61 all reside on the Inputs page.   That page is quite extensive.  So, I wanted to separate things a bit with a Results page which would draw the information from the Input page automatically. The Results page is strictly calculations.

Comment: I see you realized that you have to qualify ALL of the cell references with the proper worksheet, if that sheet is different from the one on which the formula resides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments provided by @RonRosenfeld, I can see that the correct way to write this calculation is as follows...

=SUMPRODUCT(--('Sheet1'!$E$11:$E$61>='Sheet1'!$AE$5),--('Sheet1'!$E$11:$E$61<='Sheet1'!$AF$5),--('Sheet'!$H11:$H61='Sheet'!$D$330))

Making sure that EACH element of the calculation that is being referenced is led by the appropriate page name and !.